# Specific instrument for correcting mistakes

Tags: tex-core

I'm searching a specific instrument for Latex. 
My teacher showed me it once, but i cannot remember the name.
It's functional in general is for long files, with big amount of code and formula's: when you check compiled .pdf file for mistakes and see one, you can click on it and this instrument is sends coursor right to the code with in .tex file. So it is very easy to correct mistakes. 
Maybe someone knows name for it?

Comment: Probably SyncTeX

Comment: Note that not every pdf viewer and not every text editor are able to do this – but for every operating system there are plenty that do.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in the comments.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, are you serious? This question is about 1 year old, this is not needs to be closed.

Comment: I do *not* see a reason for not closing it (this is emotionless, call it **housekeeping**).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, well, is there _someone_ who needs it to be done by **you**?

Comment: **I do not consider this topic worth discussing (again, *emotionless*): I do not plan to further reply to this topic.** More than one vote is needed to close a question: Let the voters decide. In addition, **I do not consider it a bad thing if a question is closed if it makes sense.** The alternative is to keep it unanswered for eternity,

Comment: *(Keep in mind that you might misunderstand comments since this is potentially communication across languages and cultures but without facial expressions.)*

Comment: I voted to close this question because:  1. There is a possible solution in the comments. 2. The problem may be solved by itself because either OP remembered the name of the instrument he was looking for or found an alternative after one year. 3. It is very unlikely that another User will encounter the same problem.